# how to compute highest sum in (O)N

Tags: java, big-o

So I have this 2d matrix that represents the grid. Each element contains a number.

```
     0   1   2   3
     -   -   -   -
0 -| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
1 -| 2 | 5 | 1 | 3 |
2 -| 1 | 3 | 1 | 6 |
3 -| 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
```

Given smaller square (say 2 x 2), find the greatest square summed. So each cell in the square is summed to a total.

I cannot figure a way to do this without iterating over the 2 * 2 square for every cell.

Now I am trying to find way to express this method so that at worst its O(N). Which means for this example it would at worst search 16 times correct?

Comment: So what is wrong with iterating over the 2 * 2 square for every cell? That won't change the time-complexity, which is _O(n)_, assuming `n` is the number of cells in the grid (i.e. 16 in this case). Summing the 4 cells of the 2 * 2 is a constant factor, unrelated to `n`, so it doesn't affect the time-complexity.

Comment: Incorrect. O(N) is equal to O(2N), which is equal to O(10N). You should read a little bit more about BigO notation. As long as the complexity groth is linear, it is O(N).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! I'm pretty new to it all so Im sorry if i am totally wrong. Say that ```q``` is the size of the square (q*q) is it still O(N) where ```n``` is the total number of cells in the grid. I was told if Ii move the square by one cell at a time until all combinations are seen, then that is called brute force which is O(Nq^2)

Comment: You are correct, that if you consider `q` to be a variable, then complexity is _O(nq²)_, i.e. it is linear to `n` and exponential to `q`, but for any *particular* value of `q`, complexity is _O(n)_. Your question is about `q=2` (or some "small" value of `q`, see *"smaller square"*), so complexity is _O(n)_, even though you have to sum 4 values for every cell of the grid.

Comment: @Andreas So if q is a parameter along with the grid how does O(N) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the answer below `n` is the total size of the grid, i.e. total number of cells, and `q` is the width/height of sub-grid we want to sum, i.e. `q=2` is this example.

Given input matrix from the question, say we're current at the shown location for the 2x2, and we know the sum is `11`.

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐       ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 1 │ 2 │ 4 │ 2 │       │ 1 │ 2 │ 4 │ 2 │
╠═══╪═══╬───┼───┤       ├───╬═══╪═══╬───┤
║ 2 │ 5 ║ 1 │ 3 │       │ 2 ║ 5 │ 1 ║ 3 │
╟───┼───╫───┼───┤   →   ├───╫───┼───╫───┤
║ 1 │ 3 ║ 1 │ 6 │       │ 1 ║ 3 │ 1 ║ 6 │ 
╠═══╪═══╬───┼───┤       ├───╬═══╪═══╬───┤
│ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 1 │       │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 1 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘       └───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

When we move to the right, we have to subtract the sum of the old left column (2+1=3) and add the sum of the new right column (1+1=2), to get the new 2x2 sum, which is `10`.

However, the column height is `q`, and we want to do this without time-complexity being affected by `q`.

So we need to remember the sum of each column, for the full width of the grid. We update that sum for the next row as we move right.

When we did the first row of 2x2 matrices, that left us with the following column sums:

```
╔═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╗       ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐       ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
║ 1 │ 2 │ 4 │ 2 ║       │ 1 │ 2 │ 4 │ 2 │       │ 1 │ 2 │ 4 │ 2 │
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢       ╠═══╪═══╬───┼───┤       ├───╬═══╪═══╬───┤
║ 2 │ 5 │ 1 │ 3 ║       ║ 2 │ 5 ║ 1 │ 3 │       │ 2 ║ 5 │ 1 ║ 3 │
╠═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╣   →   ╟───┼───╫───┼───┤   →   ├───╫───┼───╫───┤
│ 1 │ 3 │ 1 │ 6 │       ║ 1 │ 3 ║ 1 │ 6 │       │ 1 ║ 3 │ 1 ║ 6 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┤       ╠═══╪═══╬───┼───┤       ├───╬═══╪═══╬───┤
│ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 1 │       │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 1 │       │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 1 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘       └───┴───┴───┴───┘       └───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐       ╔═══╤═══╦───┬───┐       ┌───╦═══╤═══╦───┐
│ 3 │ 7 │ 5 │ 5 │       ║ 3 │ 8 ║ 5 │ 5 │       │ 3 ║ 8 │ 2 ║ 5 │  Column Sums
└───┴───┴───┴───┘       ╚═══╧═══╩───┴───┘       └───╩═══╧═══╩───┘
```

As we move from (x,y) = (0,1) to (1,1), we can subtract the old left column easily, since we have the sum 3 in `columnSum[0]`.

Before adding the new right column's sum, we need to update it, so we subtract (2,0) value 4 and add (2,2) value 1, giving us `columnSum[2] += grid[2][2] - grid[0][2]` aka `5 + 1 - 4 = 2`.

This is a fixed cost, unrelated to `q`, although the value of `q` is used in calculating this, in order to calculate the offset of cells to add and subtract.

Say `x,y` is the upper-left corner of the sub-matrix, then the steps for moving right are:

```
columnSum[x + q] += grid[y + q - 1][x + q] - grid[y - 1][x + q];
sum += columnSum[x + q] - columnSum[x];
x++;
```

As you can see, the code uses `q`, but has *O(1)* complexity relative to `q`.

The full code is of course more complex, getting started and progressing to the next row, but this is the essence of how to do the operation with time complexity *O(n)*, even when `q` is variable.

Comment: Thanks A lot. I did start trying this way. But to get the first sums you would need to do a nested for loop with ```n``` and ```k``` which is O(nq) isn't it? so to get the width it would be the grid row width so thats the first loop. The Second loop would be ```q``` to get the height. So therefore first loop is O(n) the second O(q) so thus O(nq)?

Comment: @Willdomybest18 It might be easier to visualize if you change `x,y` to be the *lower-right* corner of the sub-matrix. The first `q - 1` rows are not iterated to process sub-matrices, but are simply used to initialize the `columnSums` array, i.e. that is counted as part of the `n` cells being processed, and doesn't scale with `q`. Same for when you start a new row, the first `q - 1` columns are not iterated to process sub-matrices, but are reduced to collect the sum of the first sub-matrix on the row, i.e. that is counted as part of the `n` cells being processed, and doesn't scale with `q`.

Comment: In short, you're iterating over every cell of the grid exactly once. The processing of a cell depending on which area of the grid you're in: 1) top `q - 1` rows, build `columnSums`, 2) left `q - 1` columns, collect `sum`, 3) remainder, process sub-matrix. Each of the 3 is a constant cost, though 3 different costs, but constant. So result is _O(n)_. It doesn't scale with _q_.

Comment: I understand the movement of the sub-matrix but I am confused how you got the first sums of columns for every column in the matrix. I would use a nested for loop but that means O(nq). I dont understand how you cant use q here to get the column sums of all columns of length q before moving the box. Thanks heaps for the help though

Comment: The part I mean is the 3 7 5 5 column sums. Because I would need to ```for (int i = 0; i < q; i++))``` and then nest ```for(int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++);``` and then do something like ```columnSums[j] = gird[i][j];```

Comment: @Willdomybest18 As I said, you start iterating from (0,0), but you don't have your first square until you reach `(q-1, q-1)`. When `y<q-1`, you add each `grid[y][x]` to `columnSums[x]` array. When `x=0`, you reset `sum` to 0. When `x<q-1 && y>=q-1`, you update `columnSums[x]` and add to `sum`. When `x>=q-1 && y>=q-1`, you update `columnSums[x]`, add update `sum`. Yes, it's a nested loop, over `y` and over `x`, for a total of `n` cells. No other loops, so _O(n)_

Comment: The 3 7 5 5 part to get it started is confusing me. How did you sum them without using q such that ```for (int i = 0; i < q; i++);``` and then sum the get 3 7 5 5?

Comment: @Willdomybest18 I ***just told you***, you build up `columnSums` array as you *iterate*. You *compare* `x` and `y` to `q`, but you don't have an `i` loop over `q` elements.

Comment: Sorry some reason it didnt load when I sent, accidentally sent double. So is ```y``` the rows here? It would be clear to read if (0,0) correlated to (x,y). Im still loss, a nested for loop is not O(n) though, its would be (On2). Can you show an example code?

Comment: (0,0) is (x,y), but because of how arrays work, you use `grid[y][x]` when looking up in 2D arrays, that way you can do things like `row = grid[y]; cellValue = row[x]`.

Comment: position (0,0) is gird[x][y] where x = 0, y = 0 though? gird[x] is the rows gird[y] is the columns.  Can we use chat to explain it?

Comment: OMG I assumed that looping over width and height would be n^2 but I finally get what you mean. Thanks a lot.